# Is there any way to send a signal to all the processes in a program?

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, sigint

I have a program in C (Linux) with at least 5 processes and i want that if any of them fails it sends SIGINT to all the other processes. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I think if you use threads instead, you can share signals. It's a bit confusing (to me) to talk about a single program using five processes. To me, a process is a program, and parallelization is done by threading the program.

Comment: I am programming in linux. In Linux the threads are called processes.

Comment: A **process** is an execution environment that contains instructions and user-data and system-data parts. **Thread** is a smaller and lighter entity than a process or a program. **Threads** are created by a processes and have their own flow of control and stack.

Comment: There is no such thing as "all the processes in a program".

Comment: You should investigate process groups.  Sending a signal to all members of a process group is probably what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, if a thread gets stuck in a CPU loop or blocked forever, it can't send anything:)  It may, depending on the architecture of your app, for threads to exchange periodic 'heartbeat' messages and so detect that a thread has become unresponsive for an unreasonable period.  Overall, it's better to apply effort to ensure that the threads do not 'fail', (that means getting the bugs out:)

Comment: Voting to close — we need more details and preferably demonstrative code.  We don't know if/how the processes are related.  From the OP's comments, we don't know if he means "processes" or, in fact, "threads."  I suspect [there's an X behind this Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/145937), but we don't know enough to spot it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to send a signal to all the processes in a program?

Yes, if all such processes are part of the same [*process group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group#Details).

Per [the POSIX `kill()` function documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html):

> If `pid` is negative, but not `-1`, `sig` shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) whose process group ID is equal to the absolute value of `pid`, and for which the process has permission to send a signal.

[Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group#Details)

> **Details**
>
> The system call `setsid()` is used to create a new session containing
>   a single (new) process group, with the current process as both the
>   session leader and the process group leader of that single process
>   group. Process groups are identified by a positive integer, the
>   process group ID, which is the process identifier of the process that
>   is (or was) the process group leader. Process groups need not
>   necessarily have leaders, although they always begin with one.
>   Sessions are identified by the process group ID of the session leader.
>   POSIX prohibits the change of the process group ID of a session
>   leader.
>
> The system call `setpgid()` is used to set the process group ID of a
>   process, thereby either joining the process to an existing process
>   group, or creating a new process group within the session of the
>   process with the process becoming the process group leader of the
>   newly created group. POSIX prohibits the re-use of a process ID where
>   a process group with that identifier still exists (i.e. where the
>   leader of a process group has exited, but other processes in the group
>   still exist). It thereby guarantees that processes may not
>   accidentally become process group leaders.
>
> The system call `kill` is capable of directing signals either to
>   individual processes or to process groups.